# WebDriver does not find element under iframe

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send a mail through hotmail.com. 
When i'm getting to the screen of "To" and "Subject" i switched the iframe into "contentFrame" and secceed to get there.
But when i'm trying to sendkeys to the body (the body of the message), I can't find how to access this elemnt.
As i see, The body is isdine iframe named "RichText", So i have iframe inside iframe.
The body class name is "RichText" so i tried to find the element by this className without success.
I added an image with the red box which i found the element with firebug.
I'll be happy if someone can help me.
P.S - You can see the element in regular hotmail.com compose mail - body message.
Thanks,
Or.
[image]

Full html page code :
http://pastebin.com/ejM5JYyS

Comment: Please post a copy of that HTML.

Comment: Full html code of the page : http://pastebin.com/ejM5JYyS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be useful for you

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='contentFrame']")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='RichTextEditor_surface']")));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.body.innerHTML = '<br>'");

WebElement bodyOfMail = driver.switchTo().activeElement();

bodyOfMail.sendKeys("Your mail body content here");

//this is for switch back to default window from frame
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```